# How to make a unite test for mocking a random return funciton?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I need to mock the output of this function:
utils/generate_new_verification_token.py

```
from random import randint
def generate_new_verification_token():
    return ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 4)])
```

In my test file: x/test_api.py

```
class TestPhoneVerify(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(email='mock@example.com', password='12345678')
    def generate_token():
        foo = ['1111', '2222']
        return Response(random.choice(foo))

    @mock.patch('utils.generate_new_verification_token.generate_new_verification_token', 
    side_effect=generate_token)
    def test_duplicate_code_for_same_user(self, req_token):
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        res_request = self.client.post('/phone/request/', data={'phone': '4545345'})
        print(res_request.token)
```

It keeps generating random numbers other than '11111', '2222' which I am using in the mocking function. i.e it keeps using the original generate_new_verification_token function. How to solve this to use my generate_token mocking function?

Comment: your function `generate_token` is a method of your `TestPhoneVerify` object, it doesn't take `self`as argument so if your code runs it means generate_token is never called (else you'd get a TypeError). I'd suggest to take out generate_token from your class definition and your code should work else set it as @staticmethod and call it with `side_effect=TestPhoneverify.generate_token`

Comment: @Youyoun I took it out in utils/generate_new_verification_token.py and I called it in test_api file `utils.generate_new_verification_token import generate_token` and in mock decorator `@mock.patch('lenmo.phoneverify.utils.generate_new_verification_token.generate_new_verification_token', side_effect=generate_token)`, but it still using the original generate token function.

Comment: What's the method that calls `generate_new_verification_token` in `test_duplicate_code_for_same_user` ?

Comment: @Youyoun inside the function that should be called by the POST to the phone/request API and here is the line in which it get called: `new_token = generate_new_verification_token()`

Comment: how is the import of utils made in the module where you define the post function ?

Comment: @Youyoun `from utils.generate_new_verification_token import generate_new_verification_token`

Comment: I'd say use `@mock.patch('module_that_contains_post_method.generate_new_verification_token', side_effect=generate_token)`